# BEM re-using common styles

Tags: css, bem

I am trying to wrap my head around BEM with CSS and got stuck.

I have a block with elements that includes a `<ul>` that are basically tabs. Tabs all around my system would look the same so - can I have both a `.tabs` class on my `<ul>` as well as a block__element (like card__tabs )?

Or do I have to create the same set of CSS-styles for all block/elements that have tabs?

```
<div class="card">
    <ul class="card__tabs tabs">
        <li>Tab 1</li>
        <li>Tab 2</li>
    </ul>

    <p class="card__description"> Some lovely flavour text</p>
</div>
```

Question arises from utilizing something like Materialize CSS library. Or maybe I should use mixins instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use mixins or design your HTML like this:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card__tabs">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li>Tab 1</li>
            <li>Tab 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p class="card__description"> Some lovely flavour text</p>
</div>
```

Don’t be afraid to use a little extra markup. No-one is going to give you a medal for shaving off a couple of  tags.

Comment: I thought one of the main purposes of BEM was to have classes so that they are self-contained. This "card" "component" needs classes on it's items which it has no control over?

Comment: You use classes to distinguish between `block`, `element`, `modifier`.  Basically in BEM you don't use 2 or more classes on a single `html element` unless the other classes are `modifiers`. In BEM `blocks` can be nested inside any other `blocks`. Check this out https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/ :)